# Image Extension not being saved in database

Tags: php, database, image, oop, insert

I'm trying to make a small form to insert some news in a database with OOP PHP.

Everything is working well, but when i insert some image, the extension isn't being saved - only the name of the image - , so i won't be able to display it later.

Right now i have this code:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){

    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
    $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
    $preco = $_POST['preco'];
    $percurso = $_POST['percurso'];
    $lotacao = $_POST['lotacao'];
    $duracao = $_POST['duracao'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];


    $arqName = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
        $arqTemp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
        $pasta = 'img/';


    //extensao do arquivo enviado

        $extensaoTemp = explode('.',$arqName);

        $extensao = strtolower(end($extensaoTemp));

    //nome do arquivo TimesTamp

        $nome = time(). '.' . $extensao;

        $upload = move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $pasta . $nome);

        if ($upload === true)

        {



              $ficheiro = $pasta.$nome; 

              $resizeObj = new classes_ResizeClass($ficheiro); 

              $resizeObj -> resizeImage(600, 240, 'auto');

              $resizeObj -> saveImage("img/$nome", 100);

        }




    try{
        $log = new classes_UserManager($myControlPanel);
        $insert = $log->insertJob($titulo,$descricao,$categoria,$preco,$percurso,$lotacao,$duracao, $nome);
    }
    catch (invalidArgumentException $e){

        $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

And this is my function to insert:

```
public function insertJob($titulo,$descricao,$categoria,$preco,$percurso,$lotacao,$duracao,$nome){


        $myDb = $this->_controlPanel->getMyDb();
        $query = "INSERT INTO roteiros (descricao, preco, lotacao, duracao, percurso, titulo, tipo, img) VALUES ('$descricao', '$preco', '$lotacao', '$duracao', '$percurso', '$titulo', '$categoria', '$nome')";


        $result = $myDb->performQuery($query);

        if (!$result) {
            die('Something went wrong, try again: ' . mysql_error());
            header( "Refresh:3; url=insertart.php");
        }

        else {
            header( "Refresh:1; url=admin.php");
        }



    }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: you dont use or parse `$extensao` to the function

Comment: Because $nome contains both timestamp and $extensao..